# What happens when I join a game and someone is playing with the same Microsoft account?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Let's say that:

- I join a Minecraft game hosted on Xbox One from a PS4 that has my Microsoft Account linked
- I join the same game from Windows 10 using the same Microsoft Account

What would happen in this case? Are the 2 connections possible or I would get kicked from PS4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xbox account currently playing would be kicked from the server, and upon trying to rejoin, the game will give an "invalid session", prompting the user to log back in.

Note: this is multiplayer only. Singleplayer may have as many people on different connections as wanted, simply by playing while not connected to the internet.